Unable to use property validity.typeMismatch for input
The form I'm trying to validate using the Constraint Validation API rules in Javascript is not working. My input is set to
type = "email" 

however in my Javascript, I am unable to use the property I need which is validity.typeMismatch. This is an exercise to help me understand client-side form validation better.


const email = document.getElementById("mail");

email.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    email.setCustomValidity("I am expecting an email address!");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }

});
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font: 1em / 1.4 Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="mail">I would like you to provide me with an e-mail address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail" minlength="10" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>



I tried using ValidityState property, i expected it to allow me to use typeMismatch, but that did not work.

What values are you using to test this?

As far as I can tell, this is working correctly; what makes you think it's not working? What steps have you taken to debug it?

You set the custom validity message, but never report it.

@mykaf It will be reported automatically when submitting the form.

I agree that this is working. If I type an invalid address and click Submit, I get the message "I am expecting an email address". Are you expecting the error message to display while you're typing, rather than waiting for submission?

@Barmar No I simply wanted it to show the custom message if an email is invalid when submitted. It was not working for some reason on my end and it still is not. My code editor is VS code, the validity property does not pop up even as a suggestion when i try to add it to my email variable.

If it works in an ordinary browser but not VS Code, that sounds like a VS Code issue.

yes thank you! I already put in an issue report for that as long as I know it's not me and I'm doing it correctly

You didn't add the reportValidity() call.
See additional details at MDN.


const email = document.getElementById("mail");

email.addEventListener("input", (event) => {
  email.reportValidity();  // <-- Need to add this.
  if (email.validity.typeMismatch) {
    email.setCustomValidity("I am expecting an email address!");
  } else {
    email.setCustomValidity("");
  }

});
body {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #333;
  font: 1em / 1.4 Helvetica Neue, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  padding: 1em;
  margin: 0;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input:valid {
  border: 2px solid green;
}

input:invalid {
  border: 2px solid red;
}
<body>
  <form>
    <label for="mail">I would like you to provide me with an e-mail address:</label>
    <input type="email" id="mail" name="mail" minlength="10" required>
    <button>Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>




I hope this isn't really what the OP wants. It's incredibly annoying having it display error messages while you're typing the address.

it works just fine here, but for some reason it does not when I try to do it through my code editor (VS Code). The validity property does not even pop up as a suggestion.
